# Using regex to get match files name but not image files

Tags: php, regex

Files name list as a string like this:

```
ckc8.txt j8hi8h.doc 6vhellors.jpg z2heyqn.txt gmzg.gif
```

I can use `([\w.]*(hello|hi|hey)[\w.]*)` to get files name contain `hello`, `hi` and `hey`, result is:

```
j8hi8h.doc 6vhellors.jpg z2heyqn.txt
```

How to exclude it if type is image (use only regex)? result like this:

```
j8hi8h.doc z2heyqn.txt
```

**Updated：**

I tried out a best way `(\w+(hello|hi|hey)\w+\.(?!jpg|gif)\w+)`

Comment: Well obviously you have to add all file extensions to your pattern that you want _not_ to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
([\w.]*(hello|hi|hey)[\w.]*\.(?!gif))
```

Or simply add the file name to your regex as @arkascha said

To force to have an extension:

```
([\w.]*(hello|hi|hey)[\w.]*\.(?!gif)[\w]+)
```

Comment: It can exclude image files, but match files doesn't contain file extension (only j8hi8h. and z2heyqn.)

Comment: ([\w.]*(hello|hi|hey)[\w.]*\.(?!gif)[\w]+)
 So just add a word at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In the example below I've removed gif or jpg, you can just add "| grep -v newFormatToRemove" to what I've sent you:

> ```
> $ cat myFileName
> ckc8.txt j8hi8h.doc 6vhellors.jpg z2heyqn.txt gmzg.gif
>
> $ sed -e "s/ /\n/g" myFileName | grep -v gif | grep -v jpg | xargs
> ckc8.txt j8hi8h.doc z2heyqn.txt
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`(\w+[hello|hi|hey]\w+\.[doc|txt]+)`

https://gum.co/phpliveregex

Comment: That need add all file extension to regex, not good enough, but thank you. I tried out a way `([\w.]*(hello|hi|hey)[\w.]*\.(?!jpg|gif)\w+)`

Comment: This matches: `abc|def.dddddddddddddddddttttttxxxx|||||||||||||||`